# An inequality involving functional matrices: $M_2\geq M_1M_0^{-1}M_1$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $L: (-\frac12,\frac12)\to M(n\times n)$ be a continuous matrix-valued function such that each $L(t)$  is symmetric and positive definite.

Define $$M_k=\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} t^kL(t) d t$$

I want to prove or disprove that

$$M_2\geq M_1M_0^{-1}M_1$$
In other words, for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$ we have

$$\langle M_2 x, x\rangle\geq \langle M_1M_0^{-1}M_1x, x\rangle$$

This is obviously true for $n=1$ since by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have

$$\Big( \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} tL(t) d t\Big)^2\leq \Big( \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} t^2L(t) d t\Big)\Big( \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}L(t) d t\Big)$$

That is $M_1^2\leq M_2M_0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $M_0$ and $M_2$ are positive definite. By the [Schur complement characterization of block positive semidefinite matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) your matrix inequality is equivalent to
$$
Z = \begin{pmatrix} M_0 & M_1 \\ M_1 & M_2 \end{pmatrix} \geq 0\,.
$$
So it suffices to show $Z \geq 0$ and we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z &= \begin{pmatrix} \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} L(t)\mathrm{d}t & \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} tL(t)\mathrm{d}t \\ \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} tL(t)\mathrm{d}t & \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} t^2L(t)\mathrm{d}t \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\begin{pmatrix}  L(t) & t L(t) \\ t L(t) & t^2 L(t)  \end{pmatrix} \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \begin{pmatrix} I \\ t I \end{pmatrix} L(t) \begin{pmatrix} I & t I\end{pmatrix} \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} N(t) L(t) N(t)^T \mathrm{d}t
\end{aligned}
$$
where on the final line we defined $N(t) = \begin{pmatrix} I \\ t I \end{pmatrix}$. Note that as $L(t) > 0$ for all $t$ we have $N(t) L(t) N(t)^T \geq 0$ for all $t$ and thus $Z \geq 0$ and we are done.